# Subscribe to MQTT messages from an AMQP client on RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, amqp, bunny

I run a RabbitMQ node with the MQTT/WebMQTT plugins enabled.
All MQTT plugin settings use the default configuration.
Various MQTT clients are sending messages to MQTT channels.
The MQTT channel names follow the format of `devices/{device_id_here}/{special_name_here}`

I wish to subscribe to all MQTT messages that would match `devices/#/logs` in MQTT. How can I accomplish this using an AMQP client on the same broker as the MQTT users?

I am using Bunny as my (Ruby) AMQP client.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the `#` wildcard in the middle of a MQTT topic subscription as it is capable of matching multiple levels.

The correct wildcard is `+` as this only matches a single level in the topic hierarchy. E.g.

```
device/+/logs
```